# How to pass a request response to another request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, request

Using the request-promise module on an ExpressJS application, I would like to make two requests but I need the response data yielded from the first, to be passed onto the second request.

An example of what I am after, would be;

```
const options = {
    url: 'http://api.example.com/v1/token',
    method: 'GET'
};

request(options).then((response) => {
    request({
        url: 'http://api.example.com/v1/user',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { token: response.token } 
    }).then((final_response) => {
        res.send(final_response);
    });
});
```

I have omitted the error handling to keep the example short. My interest is that of a technique to pass the response from one request, to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain promises by returning them.
Something like:

```
request(options1)
  .then((response1) => {
    return request(options2)
  })
  .then((response2) => {
    return request(options3)
  })
  .then((final_response) => {
    res.send(final_response);
  });
```

Here is a nice article about [promise chaining and error handling](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-chaining).

Comment: Any idea's how I can pass the response from the first request to the second?

Comment: You can use a variable in the parent context to 'save' the result. Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/3ku6wjrr/)

Comment: Thank you, I noticed that `.then((response1) => { const this.response1 = response1 })` could be accessed in the second `.then((response2) => { const response1 = this.response1 })`.